# Minimum spanning tree between blobs

Tags: computational-geometry, minimum-spanning-tree, digital-image-processing

We have a binary raster image in which we consider the white blobs (connected components). We define a distance between two blobs to be the length of the shortest path between any two respective pixels (topological distance), or alternatively the shortest Euclidean distance between two pixels. In general the two definitions give similar results and any can be chosen for convenience.

[image]

Is there a known efficient algorithm to build the Minimum Spanning Tree of the blobs, where the edge weights are the distances ? By efficient we mean one that does not require the computation of all pairwise distances, nor a variable number of passes across the whole image.

(In the case of isolated points, the Euclidean Minimum Spanning Tree is known to be constructible in time $O(n\log(n))$ via the Voronoi diagram.)

Comment: Since your blobs are not polygons (not sure if polygons would help, but they might) and are not necessarily convex (convexity would almost certainly help), I wouldn't expect any efficient algorithms. Imagine that your blobs are weirdly shaped curves. Even efficiently computing the distance between the pair of curves sounds like a pain, so I doubt there is a good way to avoid pairwise distances.

Comment: @Dmitry: the digital Voronoi diagram of the blobs can be computed in time linear in the image size (hence in a single pass), by a process similar to computing the complete distance map. IMO that brings us closer to a solution, but does not directly give the shortest distances of interest nor the MST.

Comment: Wait, if you have the Voronoi diagram, you should be able to tell which blobs share the Voronoi's  boundary. Consider the graph where you add an edge between the blobs sharing a boundary. Then only the edges of this graph can form the MST in the original problem. Since the graph is planar, there is a linear number of pairwise distances you need to compute. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dmitry: that's it. There needs to be some process that tells which Voronoi cells come in contact, and also the shortest distance of this contact. That allows to create a graph and compute its MST. What I need to find is the way to efficiently find these contacts.

Comment: What exactly does the "digital Voronoi diagram" mean? Does it find the pixels intersecting the "true" (Euclidean) Voronoi's boundary? Can it guarantee that, if cells share a boundary of non-trivial length, then there is a pixel on the boundary that is a neighbor to pixels from both cells (or maybe a 2-hop neighbor)?

Comment: Taking a larger-hop neighborhood, we will get some false positives (i.e. report that some cells are neighbors while they are not), but, if I correctly understand what the digital Voronoi diagram is, the number of edges increases only by a constant factor. If you don't need the exact answer, even for 1-hop or 2-hop, false negatives shouldn't affect the MST objective much.

Comment: @Dmitry: digital means that every pixel is assigned to the closest pixel belonging to a blob, with ties arbitrarily broken. The metric can be Euclidean, but topological can also do (path length). I guess that this coincides with the ordinary Voronoi of the pixel centers of the blobs, provided you merge the cells of all these pixels. The exact geometry of the cell outlines is irrelevant as we only care about the raster points.

Comment: @Dmitry: in the topological case, one could fill the inter-blob space by growing the blobs layer by layer, until they come in contact. The first contact between two blobs then gives the shortest distance. (The "first" contact can occur at several places simultaneously, but that is unimportant.)

Comment: @Dmitry: on second thoughts, using such a growing process the distances between blobs will be discovered in increasing order, so if I am right, it suffices to ignore the cycles and the MST will emerge spontaneously.

Comment: Right, for the $\ell_1$ distance, growing blobs will work.